# How to prevent "back to top" scrolling in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

The result of a llm inference is saved in an output.html which is in the same directory as my app.py.

The content of this output.html is displayed when the page is loaded. For this reason
I have placed an iframe to display the content from output.html in index.html

```
  <iframe
        id="output"
        src="output.html"
        width="100%"
        height="600"
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
```

And with this js I check if there is new content in my output.html

```
setInterval(() => {
  const iframe = document.getElementById("output");
  iframe.src = "output.html";
}, 1000);
```

This works – when a user clicks a “save” button which saves the result from the llm inference ,the content is stored in output.html and every 1 second the setIntervall checks the output.html and display it’s content.

**The problem is**: When a user scrolls down within the iframe where the content from output.html is stored every one second the user gets back on top of the iFrame. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Changing `.src` essentially causes a reload.